# Is it possible to assign an animate svg to a marker symbol in google Maps JavaScript API?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, animation, svg, google-maps-api-3

I have created a symbol using a SVG. This is my symbol:

```
    var symbol = {
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(11, 11),
    url: 'data: image/svg+xml;utf-8, ' + mysvg,
    size : new google.maps.Size(22, 22)
}
```

And I have assigned it to a marker:

```
marker.setIcon(symbol);
```

My svg is the following:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1"> 
<g fill="none" stroke-width="3" transform="translate(11,11)">
<circle id="my-circle" cx="0" cy="0" r="9" stroke="darkorange" fill="seagreen" />
 </g> </svg>
```

It works perfectly but in some cases I need to animate the marker so I have created the following animate svg to assign it to my marker:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1"> 
<g fill="none" stroke-width="3" transform="translate(11,11)">
<circle id="my-circle" cx="0" cy="0" r="9" stroke="darkorange" fill="seagreen" />
<animate href="#my-circle" attributeName="opacity"  values="1;-2" dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite" /> </g> </svg>
```

And I have created a new symbol in the same way as before:

```
var animatedsymbol = {
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(11, 11),
    url: 'data: image/svg+xml;utf-8, ' + myanimatesvg,
    size : new google.maps.Size(22, 22)
}
```

And I asigne it to the marker:

```
marker.setIcon(animatedsymbol);
```

But It doesn't work, the marker is not showed. I suspect that google maps api markers doesn't support this kind of animated svgs. Does anyone know if it does suport animated svgs? If it does, Do you have any hint of what I am doing wrong?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is no problem of doing that. Check this code:

```js
var svgNonAnimated = btoa([
  '<?xml version="1.0"?>',
  '<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">',
  '<g fill="none" stroke-width="3" transform="translate(11,11)">',
  '<circle id="my-circle" cx="0" cy="0" r="9" stroke="darkorange" fill="seagreen" />',
  '</g></svg>'
].join('\n'));

var svgAnimated = btoa([
  '<?xml version="1.0"?>',
  '<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">',
  '<g fill="none" stroke-width="3" transform="translate(11,11)">',
  '<circle id="my-circle" cx="0" cy="0" r="9" stroke="darkorange" fill="seagreen" />',
  '<animate href="#my-circle" attributeName="opacity"  values="1;-2" dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite" />',
  '</g></svg>'
].join('\n'));


function initMap() {
  var center = new google.maps.LatLng(33.53625, -111.92674);

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: center,
    zoom: 13
  });

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: center,
    map: map,
    title: 'Dynamic SVG Marker',
    icon: getIcon(false),
    optimized: false
  });

  var isAnimated = false;
  document.getElementById('toggleAnimation').addEventListener('click', function() {
    isAnimated = !isAnimated;
    marker.setIcon(getIcon(isAnimated));
  });

  function getIcon(animated) {
    return animated ? {
      url: 'data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8;base64,' + svgAnimated,
      scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(50, 50)
    } : {
      url: 'data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8;base64,' + svgNonAnimated,
      scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(50, 50)
    };
  }

}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{
  display:none !important;
}
```

```html
<script async defer type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&callback=initMap"></script>

<div id="map" style="width:400px;height:150px;float:left"></div>
<button id="toggleAnimation" style="float: left;width: 70px;text-align: center;font-size: 11px;">Toggle Animate</button>
```

*This works in Chrome and Firefox, but in IE11 I see only the svg without the animation ...*

Comment: Thanks. Your code works perfectly, so now I know there is no problem of doing that. It continues not working in my code, but I have great hints in your answer so I supose I will manage to aply it. Thank you again.

Comment: @LaiaLinaresOrtells this sounds great. I'm glad that my answer will help you. Just pay attention that this code was to working in IE11(need a work around)